# recover value of these three fields Odoo 10

Tags: python, odoo

I want to recover the value of these 3 fields which is in my model `ecole.webservices`. The search allows me to recover all the identifiers of the table. I want to recover the active elements.
But I do not know how to recover the value of the fields `code_produit`, `code_CDG` and `code_Catalog`. What am I doing wrong? Here is my class:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from odoo import models, fields, api

class SchoolWebServices(models.Model):

    _name = 'ecole.webservices'

    name = fields.Char(string='Nom')
    code_produit = fields.Char(string='Produit')
    code_CDG = fields.Char(string='Centre de Gestion')
    code_Catalog = fields.Char(string='Catalogue Produits')
```

My function :

```
    datas_webservices = self.env['ecole.webservices'].search([])
    code_produit = datas_webservices.code_produit
    code_CDG = datas_webservices.code_CDG
    code_Catalog = datas_webservices.code_Catalog
```

Comment: Please help me for my problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Make sure that some values are stored in *ecole.webservices*

```
datas_webservices = self.env['ecole.webservices'].search([])
for data in datas_webservices
    code_produit = data.code_produit
    code_CDG = data.code_CDG
    code_Catalog = data.code_Catalog
```

Comment: Thank you. I modify my question. 
I want to recover the active elements.
How to do ? Thanks

Comment: The values ​​are well stored yes since if I limit = 1 to my search, it gets me the first line. However, I would like to get a record when I select a name field value of the 'school.webservices' model. Thank you